# First time connect without networking

Tags: raspbian, screen, login

The BeagleBone (BB) has this nice feature that you can `screen` in using the usb connection to the BB to set up your wireless the first time around. When you plug in the BB, after it boots eventually a **/dev/tty** device shows up so you can `screen /dev/ttyXXX 115200`.

Does the Raspberry Pi have this capability? Or do you always have to use a crossover cable to ssh in to the R. Pi the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do you always have to use a crossover cable to ssh

You would only have to use a crossover cable if you were connecting from an old machine using an ethernet NIC without [auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X), which most contemporary controllers, including the one on the pi, do have.  So FYI: Not much purpose to crossover cables now-a-days.

Anyway, to nitpick with more relevance, SSH is an IP based protocol so can only be used over a genuine IP link -- plain serial is not.

However, you can arrange for a login serial console like the one you describe from the Beaglebone, and Raspbian has this enabled by default.  Unfortunately, in the Pi's case this is accessed via the UART pins on the breakout.  It's also 3.3V logic only, so to use it with a normal PC you'd need a USB-serial cable (and a level shifter, if the cable presumes 5V).

Comment: Unfortunately the Pi3 disables serial, so you need to modify `config.txt` for serial console.